# Combine dplyr mutate function with a search through the whole table

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm quite new to R and especially to the tidy verse. I'm trying to write a script with which we can rewrite a list of taxons. We already have one using quite a lot for and if loops and I want to try to simplify it with the tidyverse, but I'm kind of stuck how to do that.

what I have is a table that looks something like that (really simplified)

```
taxon_file<- tibble(name = c( "cockroach","cockroach2", "grasshopper", "spider",    "lobster",  "insect",   "crustacea",    "arachnid"), 
                Id = c(445,448,446,778,543,200,400,300),
                parent_ID = c(200,200,200,300,400,200,400,300),
                rank = c("genus","genus","genus","genus","genus","order","order","order")
                )    


+-------------+-----+-----------+----------+
|    name     | Id  | parent_ID |   rank   |
+=============+=====+===========+==========+
| cockroach   | 445 | 200       | genus    |
| cockroach2  | 448 | 200       | genus    |
| grasshopper | 446 | 200       | genus    |
| spider      | 778 | 300       | genus    |
| lobster     | 543 | 400       | genus    |
| insect      | 200 | 200       | order    |
| crustacea   | 400 | 400       | order    |
| arachnid    | 300 | 300       | order    |
+-------------+-----+-----+------------+----------+
```

Now I want to rearrange it so that I get a new column where I can add the order that matches the parent_ID (so when parent_ID == ID then write name in column order). The end result should look kinda like this

```
+-------------+------------+------+-----------+
|    name     |    order   |  Id  | parent_ID |
+=============+============+======+===========+
| cockroach   |  insect    |  445 |       200 |
| cockroach2  |  insect    |  448 |       200 |
| grasshopper |  insect    |  446 |       200 |
| spider      |  arachnid  |  778 |       300 |
| lobster     |  crustacea |  543 |       400 |
+-------------+------------+------+-----------+
```

I tried to combine mutate with an ifelse statement but this just adds NA's to the whole order column.

tibble is named taxon_list

```
taxon_list %>%    
   mutate(order = ifelse(parent_ID == Id, Name, NA))
```

I know this will not work because it doesn't search the whole data-set for the correct row (that's what I did before with alle the for loops). Maybe someone can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hello. A couple of things; Make sure you provide reproducible examples. You can do that using `dput(head(your_df))`. Also, What do you mean `parent_ID == Id`? In your example Parent_ID is not equal with any `Id` but you still have the `order` column

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I edited the original post a bit, hope it explained a bit more that way. I have a workable solution now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to `filter` to each rank type to 2 separate dfs, subset using `select`, and `merge` the 2.

```
  df <- tibble(name = c( "cockroach","cockroach2", "grasshopper", "spider",    "lobster",  "insect",   "crustacea",    "arachnid"), 
                  Id = c(445,448,446,778,543,200,400,300),
                  parent_ID = c(200,200,200,300,400,200,400,300),
                  rank = c("genus","genus","genus","genus","genus","order","order","order"))     

library(tidyverse)

df_order <- df %>%
  filter(rank == "order") %>% 
  select(order = name, parent_ID)

df_genus <- df %>%
  filter(rank == "genus") %>% 
  select(name, Id, parent_ID) %>% 
  merge(df_order, by = "parent_ID")
```

Result:

```
  parent_ID        name  Id     order
1       200   cockroach 445    insect
2       200  cockroach2 448    insect
3       200 grasshopper 446    insect
4       300      spider 778  arachnid
5       400     lobster 543 crustacea
```